# Type mismatch: expected a map but was List{map} in apoc

Tags: xml, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

xml document

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lei:LEIData
    xmlns:lei="http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/leidata/2016" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/leidata/2016 schemas/2016-11-30_LEI-CDF-2-0_XML_Schema_Final.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <lei:LEIHeader>
        <lei:ContentDate>2020-12-08T23:33:04.799Z</lei:ContentDate>
        <lei:Originator>5493001KJTIIGC8Y1R12</lei:Originator>
        <lei:FileContent>LOU_FULL_PUBLISHED</lei:FileContent>
        <lei:RecordCount>118125</lei:RecordCount>
    </lei:LEIHeader>
    <lei:LEIRecords>
        <lei:LEIRecord>
            <lei:LEI>01ERPZV3DOLNXY2MLB90</lei:LEI>
            <lei:Entity>
                <lei:LegalName>Libertyville Bank &amp; Trust Company, N.A.</lei:LegalName>
                <lei:LegalAddress>
                    <lei:FirstAddressLine>507 North Milwaukee Avenue</lei:FirstAddressLine>
                    <lei:City>Libertyville</lei:City>
                    <lei:Region>US-IL</lei:Region>
                    <lei:Country>US</lei:Country>
                    <lei:PostalCode>60048</lei:PostalCode>
                </lei:LegalAddress>
                <lei:HeadquartersAddress>
                    <lei:FirstAddressLine>507 North Milwaukee Avenue</lei:FirstAddressLine>
                    <lei:City>Libertyville</lei:City>
                    <lei:Region>US-IL</lei:Region>
                    <lei:Country>US</lei:Country>
                    <lei:PostalCode>60048</lei:PostalCode>
                </lei:HeadquartersAddress>
                <lei:RegistrationAuthority>
                    <lei:RegistrationAuthorityID>RA000744</lei:RegistrationAuthorityID>
                    <lei:RegistrationAuthorityEntityID>34073</lei:RegistrationAuthorityEntityID>
                </lei:RegistrationAuthority>
                <lei:LegalJurisdiction>US-IL</lei:LegalJurisdiction>
                <lei:LegalForm>
                    <lei:EntityLegalFormCode>8888</lei:EntityLegalFormCode>
                    <lei:OtherLegalForm>N.A.</lei:OtherLegalForm>
                </lei:LegalForm>
                <lei:EntityStatus>ACTIVE</lei:EntityStatus>
            </lei:Entity>
            <lei:Registration>
                <lei:InitialRegistrationDate>2012-06-06T15:54:00.000Z</lei:InitialRegistrationDate>
                <lei:LastUpdateDate>2020-06-22T15:46:49.014Z</lei:LastUpdateDate>
                <lei:RegistrationStatus>ISSUED</lei:RegistrationStatus>
                <lei:NextRenewalDate>2021-06-01T00:31:00.000Z</lei:NextRenewalDate>
                <lei:ManagingLOU>5493001KJTIIGC8Y1R12</lei:ManagingLOU>
                <lei:ValidationSources>FULLY_CORROBORATED</lei:ValidationSources>
                <lei:ValidationAuthority>
                    <lei:ValidationAuthorityID>RA000744</lei:ValidationAuthorityID>
                    <lei:ValidationAuthorityEntityID>34073</lei:ValidationAuthorityEntityID>
                </lei:ValidationAuthority>
            </lei:Registration>
        </lei:LEIRecord>
</lei:LEIRecords>
</lei:LEIData>
```

error I am facing.

```html
Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError
Type mismatch: expected a map but was List{Map{_type -> String("ContentDate"), _text -> String("2020-12-08T23:33:04.799Z")}, Map{_type -> String("Originator"), _text -> String("5493001KJTIIGC8Y1R12")}, Map{_type -> String("FileContent"), _text -> String("LOU_FULL_PUBLISHED")}, Map{_type -> String("RecordCount"), _text -> String("118125")}}
```

I am running the below command.

```html
CALL apoc.load.xml("file:///Bloomberg_LEI_data.xml")
YIELD value as lei 
UNWIND lei._children as record
WITH record._children as leirecord
WHERE leirecord._type=("LEIRecord")
RETURN leirecord._children
```

I want to get the LEI:ID and compare it with some other xml data.( which also contains ID )  get the relationship between those two xml documents.

I am using apoc in neo4j database to obtain relationship between xml documents.
What am I missing , How can I solve this issue and how to obtain relationship between two xml documents in apoc .
Any help / resources to solve this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the query entered is not correct and is not able to fetch the lei record details.
I am still unaware , how we could integrate both but I seem to find a way to fetch the ids of both xml datasets.
Though I am interested in knowing better answers for fetching the ids and integrating both xml datasets using neo4j and cypher query language.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just interested in the nested elements, you can use xpath:
`call apoc.load.xml("file:/Bloomberg_LEI_data.xml.xml",'/lei:LEIData/lei:LEIHeader/lei:LEIRecords',{}, false) yield value as LEI`

Comment: I am interested in getting ids of both xml datasets.
I can get an id of of one dataset but getting id of another dataset and integrating both datasets to find correlation is something I am facing problems with.

Comment: so you need to import the two different datasets, merge them as node by ID, and simply compare them.

Comment: any help on how you can achieve the above mentioned functionality any documentation/guides would be helpful.